# Sequential vs Parallel streams - changes to ordering that are introduced by intermediate and terminal operations

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

While looking into parallel streams i had problems finding a good summary of the effect that intermediate/terminal operations have on the ordered/unordered processing of the stream members, obviously in the parallel case . Something in the lines of :

```
InputCollection -> intermediate op effect -> terminal op effect -> result order.
```

Like(just a random guess, don't assume its correctness)

```
Set (unord) -> peek(no change) -> flatMap(ord/sequentialStrm) ->  forEach(unord)
```

Is there a good summary/table or a general rule that i am missing. 
I can obviously test them one by one, but with the kind of random outcome of parallel processing, it doesn't feel as productive.

I checked the related questions but they are always discussing special cases and not in general.

Comment: It’s not clear what your example is aiming at. If the source is already unordered, there is no order to preserve. Besides that, the effects are either [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) or self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this Java 8 Streams cheat sheet by zeroturnaround?
https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-streams-cheat-sheet/

TL:DR The hotlink to the image referenced:
https://zeroturnaround.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Java-8-Streams-cheat-sheet-by-RebelLabs.png